# How to use map() with dictionary comprehension in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to use map() on a list of dictionaries to get a name and id only.

My input:

```
employees = [
   {"id": 12113, "name": "Jim", "department": "Sales"},
   {"id": 12342, "name": "Michael", "department": "Management"},
   {"id": 23312, "name": "Dwight", "department": "Sales"},
]
```

What I want my function to return is a dictionary where each key is the employee's name and the value is the employee's ID.

My function currently contains what is below but isn't returning values, only: `<map object at 0x7f3b0bb6d460>, <map object at 0x7f78e7242670>`.

My code:

```
def name_id(employees):

   name_and_ids = [{map(('name', 'id'), emp) for emp in employees}]
   print(list(name_id)) ### to see if what I want is being output or not
   return name_and_ids
```

I am calling my function with:

```
  print(f"Name and ids: {name_id(employees)}")
```

I am fairly new to python and am getting confused with comprehensions in general, whether list or dictionary comprehensions. I did see you can use `dict` and/or `zip` but would like to learn something new with map().

Any advice/help to push me in the right direction of getting what I want would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want my function to return is a dictionary where each key is the employee's name and the value is the employee's ID.

You need a dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {
    emp['name']: emp['id']
    for emp in employees
}
```

`map` is not an appropriate tool for the job, because it converts N things to N other things, whereas you need to convert N things (3 employees) into one thing (a dict). If you insist, you could use `map` to convert the source list into a list of key-value tuples and then apply `dict` to the result:

```
from operator import itemgetter

result = dict(
    map(itemgetter('name', 'id'), employees)
)
```

This style is not considered "pythonic" though.

Comment: Thank you. Just wondering as well why this isn't considered Pythonic?

Comment: @Krasnips: just compare both snippets. The first one tells simply and unequivocally  what we're doing, and uses zero functions.  The second one is cryptic, uses three functions, which you need to look up in the docs, and one extra import. Python is all about simplicity and clarity.

Comment: Rather than trying to assess if one thing is Pythonic and another is not, I think it's often better to consider if one is *more pythonic* than the other. In this case, the dict comprehension is more Pythonic because it uses Python syntax features to good effect, making for easy to understand code. The second version might be preferred by some kinds of functional programmers (who love `map`), but takes much less advantage of Python's potential for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

The `map` function doesn't do anything related to what you want here. It's leading you astray.

Instead, just do the mapping you want yourself in the dict comprehension you already have:

```
name_and_ids = {emp['name']: emp['id'] for emp in employees}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. I have much to learn both in terms what does what and when/how to use them. I also see you can iterate over them, for example, if you just want the first letter of each name, you just update to ```emp['name'][0]```. Interesting. Thank you!